# How to Create Full Screen Application without Status bar in Ionic 3 / Crodova

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to create an application in Ionic3/Cordova/Angular with a full screen.

I have searched a lot but could not find a working solution.
I have tried https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar but failed (not sure if it was a bad implementation)

I want the application to be in Full Screen without the Status bar in both iOS and Android, from the start till every page in the application.

using     `status.hide()`   make it full screen but not during startup - splash screen.

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public status: StatusBar) {
    status.hide();
  }
```

Really appreciate any help!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use Ionic Native status bar:

```
npm install @ionic-native/core --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar
```

Add Plugins to Your App's Module

```
    ` ...

        import { StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

    ...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    StatusBar
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }

`
```

And then use it in your rootPage or app.component.ts:

```
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

   constructor(platform: Platform) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.hide();

    });
  }
```

For more information : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/

Comment: using it here, when the device is ready.. means we are already passed the Ionic splash screen (after ionic have been initialized)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it inside the `this.platform.ready()` event as shown below.Maybe you can think about `ionViewDidEnter()` life cycle event instead of `constructor()` too.

```
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private status: StatusBar) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.status.hide();
    });
  }
```

Comment: The implementation i used and gave as example in my question is actually working, my problem is making it full screen from start. meaning from the moment you open the app (the moment when the ionic splash screen starts)

Comment: Hope you can give above on `app.component.ts` file no? @Melchia also mentioned that in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class in header

```
<ion-header class="absent-header">
```

and use the corresponding scss file to hide it.

```
page-home {
   .absent-header {
        display: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to index.html.

It works on iOS for me but it doesn't hide text of status bar.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```